# AJAX - Do not do a GET request if POST is in action

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a textbox where you can type. The textbox constantly gets data from database. The user can type on the textbox and it will save it in database on `keyup`. The issue is that sometimes when I'm typing, it gets replaced with the GET request from database, which replaces the value of the text area.

What I want to achieve is that when the user is typing, and the POST requests occurs on the `keyup` function, GET request is cancelled. When the user is not typing, GET request is continued.

My Code:

```
function timers() {

            tmrAjax = setInterval(function () {

                $.get('<?php echo base_url('home/get') ?>',  function (html) {

                    $("[name=text]").attr('id', 'text');
                    $("#text").val(html);
                    //   $("#text").removeAttr("disabled");
                });
            }, 1000);
        }

        timers();

        $(window).blur(function () {
            clearInterval(tmrAjax);
            $("#text").removeAttr("id");
            //  $("#text").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }).focus(timers);


$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#text").keyup(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/save",
                        data: "text=" + $("#text").val()
                        //onsuccess
                        //onerror
                        //etc
                    });
            });
 });
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in that case you should be putting your get inside your 'on success' function, that way it will be synchronized.

Comment: But the `onsuccess` will happen only if the `keyup` event occurs. If the user refreshes the page and doesn't type anything, it will not show any new data from database unless the `keyup` event occurs.

Comment: I am lost then, what is the get retrieving and ultimately showing from database.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. The GET is happening every one second and check for new data from database. If the data is modified or new data is added, the textbox's value will be replaced with the new data. You see, you can type in the textbox and the data can be edited directly from the textbox and will be saved in the database. The POST happens when there is a keyup function. The GET happens when the page loads. If I put the GET inside the `onsuccess`, the GET will not happen unless the user types something.

Comment: Ok so you can create a a function where you put the get and also use for inside the success function. That way you can initialize your textbox to show what you have in database. Also, as far as I know you should not be doing call every second. If I am right, your 'get' is the same info that you are storing from your 'post', that being said you should be 'getting' only when a 'post' happens. Not every second!